# Setting up a Wi-Fi hotspot on iOS13

Tags: wifi, windows, tethering, ios

I am trying to set up a wifi hotspot using my iPhone XR running iOS 13, which I wish to connect to using my Windows 7 Pro laptop. On the iPhone I go to Settings | Personal Hotspot and switch on, and I have set the name and password of the network. Then on the laptop I can see the name of the network, and I can connect to it.

The problem is that it's showing on the laptop as unconnected to the internet even when the iPhone is definitely connected to the internet because I can browse the web with it. What settings do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a couple of reasons for it.

**First option, try applying these tweaks:**

1. Disable or turn off Personal Hotspot.
2. Sign out from iCloud.
3. Restart your other device.
4. Sign in to iCloud again.
5. Then re-enable Personal Hotspot.

After refreshing and enabling Personal Hotspot on both your iPhone  and other device, retry connecting through Wi-Fi.

**Second option, toggle Airplane Mode on and off.**

This is another simple old trick you can try to get rid of minor errors affecting the phone’s wireless radios including Cellular Data and Personal Hotspot. It works by giving a quick restart to the Wi-Fi features on the phone. Here’s how it’s done:

1. Tap **Settings** from the Home screen.
2. Select **Airplane Mode**.
3. Toggle the Airplane Mode switch to turn the feature ON. This will disable wireless radios on the phone.
4. While Airplane mode is enabled, turn your iPhone off and then back on again.
5. After it boots up, go back to **Settings**-> **Airplane Mode** menu.
6. Then toggle the switch to disable Airplane Mode again. Wireless radios on the phone are then re-enabled.

After performing the Airplane mode, go to your iPhone **Settings**->**Mobile Data** menu, then make sure that Mobile Data is enabled. If necessary, toggle the switch to enable the feature.

**Third option, Reset network settings on your iPhone**

This will erase your Wi-Fi networks and other network-related settings and server settings on the phone. Network errors and Internet problems that are tied to incorrect network configurations are likewise cleared out in the process. Here’s how it’s done:

1. From the Home screen, tap on **Settings**.
2. Tap **General**.
3. Scroll down to and tap **Reset**.
4. Select the option to **Reset network settings**.
5. If prompted, enter your device passcode.
6. Then tap the option to confirm network settings reset.

Your iPhone will reboot automatically when the reset is finished. As soon as it boots up, set up and reconnect to your Wi-Fi network or enable Mobile Data and Personal Hotspot to retry using and sharing your Internet connection with your other devices

Comment: Please see the linked question too.. :)

Comment: @Udhy - Many thanks for this. The first method I'm trying is your Option 2. I followed steps 1-6, but I have no Settings | Cellular menu. I'm using iOS 13.

Comment: @ruffle, Cellular menu means Mobile Data :) and check the last option too.

Comment: None of the methods suggested here or on the other page are working for me. I don't use syncing or the cloud. I tried to downgrade back to iOS 12, but this requires an Apple "signature" on the earlier OS version, a signature the company has now removed. It [seems](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250664015) they know iOS 13 messed up tethering and they're working on a fix as a high priority. I hope they find one soon, because one of the main reasons I bought my iPhone was to run a hotspot that my laptop can connect to the internet through.